# Как изменить цвет счетчика в метке кластеризатора в yandex maps?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

На сайте используются карты яндекса, на которых показываются разные метки. Реализовано через objectManager. Для меток используются свои изображения, в том числе для меток кластеризатора. В метках кластеризатора выводится счетчик объединенных меток. Перерыв документацию яндекса и пошарив по гуглу не нашел информации о том, как меняется цвет этого счетчика на метке кластеризатора.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки поменять цвет этого счетчика?

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует самостоятельно задать шаблон для **clusterIconContentLayout** менеджера объектов. Значение вложенных объектов при этом получить можно через **properties.geoObjects.length**. [Пример есть](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ClusterPlacemark.html?lang=ru) в документации.

```
MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div style="color: #FF0000;">$[properties.geoObjects.length]</div>'),

objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    clusterIconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
});
```